# Structure/description of a finitely presented group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I am unable to see the structure of the following finitely presented group.
$$\langle a,b,c,d : [a,b]=c=a^p,\ [c,b]=c^p=d^p,\ b^{p^2}=c^{p^2}=1 \rangle$$
I have tried in GAP, but it is not showing any result. Kindly help me out. This presentation is given in the following article by the name of the group $\phi_8(321)b$ on the page 324 under the class of groups of order $p^6$. How to present it in simple way ? ( Here $[a,c]=[b,d]=[a,d]=[c,d]=1$ )

Reference : *James, Rodney*, [**The groups of order (p^6) ((p) an odd prime).**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2006106), Math. Comput. 34, 613-637 (1980). [ZBL0428.20013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0428.20013).

Comment: It is easy to see that the above presentation defines an infinite group.  I am guessing that there is a convention (which is often used in presentations of finite $p$-groups) that a pair of generators commutes unless otherwise specified. So you need to add the relations $[a,c]=[a,d]=[b,d]=[c,d]=1$ to the presentation.

Comment: With the extra relations you can define it in GAP for small primes, and it does indeed define a group of order $p^6$. I am not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Derek In GAP, it is not loading, I have tried for $p=3$. Here, in the presentation $$a^{p^3}=b^{p^2}=d^{p^2}=1$$. Since, $a,b$ and $d$ are generators. My question is do the structure involve some kind of non split extension ??

Comment: One immediate observation is that this group is the central product of its subgroups $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ and $\langle d \rangle$ of order $p^5$ and $p^2$, so this effectively reduces your question to a question about the smaller group $\langle a,b,c \rangle$, which has nilpotency class 3.

Comment: Well every nonabelian finite $p$-group $P$  is a nonsplit extension of $Z(P)$ by $P/Z(P)$ for example, so you need to ask more precise questions.

Comment: I am sorry for that. Actually, I have not studied non-split extensions and I am very less familiar with central products. Therefore I was surprised to see that why the product of powers of generators is coming more than $p^6$. So, it must involve something other than direct or semidirect product is all I thought. Thank you for the answer. It really is helping me out.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can somehow I change $a^p$ to $a^{p^2}$ by keeping the structure preserved or I will say by keeping the group unaffected ?